# 'cannot associate a contact with a consumer account' - getting this error while converting lead

Tags: lead-conversion, person-accounts

[image]

Refer below log:

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: **CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, We can't save this record because the “Account Process” process failed.** Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: **INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: Can not select a person account.** You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 2114044819-202802 (-159166518)k up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 2114044819-202802 (-159166518): []

Answer (score 0):

Hello it looks like the flow **Account Process** failed. You can:

1. Try checking the flow. OR
2. Deactivate the flow and try converting the lead again.

However, for person accounts here are a few things to note:

Firstly, you have to enable person accounts, in order to use them; this can be done by the following steps below: 
Setup -> Search for Person Accounts in the quick find box -> Configure all the steps mentioned there and enable person accounts.

Once you have done the steps above, please make sure to follow the steps given by salesforce, to make changes to the user profile:
[image: Steps from Salesforce, after enabling Person Accounts]

Once you have done that, there are several things to note here:
You can only assign person account when converting lead, if the **company** field on the lead is not populated. (source: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8RhLSAV)

There are a few ways to do this:

1. Easiest one I can think of is to edit the Lead Layout and remove the required settings from the Company field [image]

So now, when you create a lead, if the company field is **NOT POPULATED**, then when converting you **can** choose a person account. 
 However, if company field is populated, you **CANNOT** choose a person account.

If you have done all of these steps and still getting the error, then I suspect it must be something to do with the **Account Process** flow.